# Salvar dados associados com CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp

Boa tarde. Estou tentado salvar dados associados no CakePHP 3. Para isto, criei três tabelas: vendas(id, nome_cliente), produtos(id, produto) e produtos_vendas(id, produtos_id, vendas_id).

Em venda table eu realizei a associação:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Produtos', [
 'foreignKey' => 'vendas_id',
 'targetForeignKey' => 'produtos_id',
 'joinTable' => 'produtos_vendas'
]);
```

Em produtos table eu realizei a associação:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Vendas', [
 'foreignKey' => 'produtos_id',
 'targetForeignKey' => 'vendas_id',
 'joinTable' => 'produtos_vendas'
]);
```

No controller Vendas eu salvo com os seguintes dados:

```
{ 
  "nome_cliente": "João",
  "produto": "maça"
}
```

Utilizando o código :

```
$venda = $this->Vendas->newEntity();

$venda = $this->Vendas->patchEntity($venda, $this->request->data);

if ($this->Vendas->save($venda)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('The venda has been saved.'));
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('The venda could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

Os dados são salvos na tabela vendas, mas não são salvos na tabela associativa.
Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava no "data". Estava faltando eu passar o(s) id(s) da tabela "produtos".
Ao invés de passar:

```
{ 
  "nome_cliente": "João",
  "produto": "maça"
}
```

Eu deveria passar:

```
{ 
  "nome_cliente": "João",
  "produtos": [{"id": 12}, {"id": 26}, {"id": 50}]
}
```

Assim eu referencio quais produtos (a partir do seu id) eu quero relacionar a uma entidade da tabela vendas.